# Bundling with subdirectories and Areas not working in release mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC web site that has an Area called admin. I use TinyMCE in both the root pages and in some admin pages. 
In the dev environment everything work correctly but in the release environment the TinyMCE.js file gets loaded as part of the bundle but the plugins and other js files that go along with it don't load.

If I set Debug to true everything works correctly.

My bundle looks like this:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
                    ));

  var tinyMCEBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/tinymce").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/tinymce", "*.js", true);
  bundles.Add(tinyMCEBundle);
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/tinymce")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/tinymce", "*.js", true));
```

It works for me on my project.

Comment: Bundle instead of ScriptBundle? Otherwise it is just the same as I have